# Loading Local Library in R with Prerequisites Together

Tags: r, install.packages

For example, I have a local `broom` package, which has several prerequisite libraries such as `backports`.

```
install.packages("broom",lib=file.path(Sys.getenv("userprofile"),"desktop","project"))
```

I found that the following `library` does not load the necessary prerequisites together.

```
library(broom,lib.loc=file.path(Sys.getenv("userprofile"),"desktop","project"))
```

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘broom’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'pillar', details:
  call: loadNamespace(name)
  error: there is no package called ‘crayon’
```

I already have those prerequisites since `install.packages` downloads them together. Should one load all the prerequisite libraries (such as `backports`) before loading the package I want to use (*i.e.,* `broom`)?

Comment: You usually don't need to specify dependencies when you load a library. Are you sure dependencies are really installed in `file.path(Sys.getenv("userprofile"),"desktop","project")`?

Comment: Yes, the first code installs ```backports``` as well as ```broom``` to the desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this function that basically loads the dependencies of the passed packages now all you need to do is run it before loading `broom` then it'll load the dependencies.

```
# loads dependencies of passed packages
# can be used in two forms :
#     load.dep(broom, tidyr)
#.    load.dep("broom", "tidyr")
load.dep <- function(...){
    x <- as.list(substitute(...()))
    stopifnot(length(x)>0)
    x <- sapply(x, as.character)
    avp <- available.packages()
    pkgs <- unlist(strsplit(avp[x, c("Imports","Depends")], split=" ?(\\([^)]+?\\))?, ?"), use.names=F)
    invisible(lapply(pkgs[!grepl('^(\\n|R )', pkgs)], library, character.only=T))
}
```